# How to bind ports for TCP clients when using raw packet sending TCP packets in Python?

Tags: python, c, sockets, tcp

I want to simulate a TCP handshake with Python. For example, I want to establish a connection from `192.168.0.101:1234` to `192.168.1.102:80`. I followed [this program](http://www.binarytides.com/python-syn-flood-program-raw-sockets-linux/) and wrote a similar program sending an SYN packet to the server. The server responds an SYN+ACK packet to me, but my operating system sends an RST packet immediately, interrupting the communication.

Thus, I hope to let the client listen to the 1234 port and do no respond automatically. However, after I bind the address with `socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)`, the Python module sends the RST packets, instead of the system.

How can I achieve such goal? I think I should control the Inernet Layer, but I have no idea how to do that.

Thank you.

Comment: The problem is that you're using the *same* address as your operating system. Well, depending on your OS, you could program your firewall so that it *drops* packets *from* 192.168.1.102:80 altogether...

Comment: It seems that the only way is using iptables block any outgoing RST packets, because the behaviour of the TCP queue inside the system cannot be affected by any sockets.